# possible ways to import an excel spreadsheet to a sharepoint 2010 list?

Tags: excel, excel-services, list

I am running SharePoint Server 2010 and I have an excel spreadsheet of about 3000 rows / 30 columns, which I would like to import to a SharePoint list.

I've seen on codeplex a free tool for MOSS/wss 3.0 but nothing for 2010.

Only option I can think of is writing an app that will go through each line of the spreadsheet and create a new list item for each.

Can anyone else think of any options for getting this data into a list?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new list based on an Excel document. Here are some walk-thrus:

http://www.bloggix.com/archive/2010/06/15/import-and-export-data-between-excel-2010-and-sharepoint-2010/

http://sharepointbuzzer.wordpress.com/2010/10/22/import-excel-sheet-as-sharepoint-list/

Answer (score 3):

There is the option of using datasheet view to copy-paste data, especially if need lookups to other lists or have "choices" already set up. This does require you to normalize the data in your spreadsheet. The downside is that you can't paste in data for columns that are "multi-line" type in datasheet view.

Using the above two walk-throughs, you can first use the "Import Excel Spreadsheet" function for your import, then create the final "destination" fields - say if you need lookups, and use the datasheet view to "convert" data from the old columns to the final fields by copying-pasting from one column to another.

Answer (score 2):

Importing spreadsheet is an inbuilt option in SharePoint 2010. You can follow these steps mentioned over here in this video demo -http://www.sharepoint-videos.com/sp10import-spreadsheet-to-create-a-new-list/

Answer (score 0):

Importing an excel Spreadsheet directly into SharePoint list won't transfer columns types like Person or group with correct lookup functionality instead it will import them as single line or multiple lines of text